# Bootstrapping AngularJS + Typescript + ASP.NET MVC6

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, requirejs, typescript1.8

I am building a new Web Application.

The architectural structure should be:
Modularized AngularJS (1.5.x) with Typescript & Bootstrap (3.x) in an ASP.NET MVC 6/Core Application.
So an angularJS application with different modules & components in the Angular2-style inside a multipage - ASP.NET MVC Application.

So I set everything up in VS2015:

- wwwroot
- - lib (client-libraries: angular, bootstrap, jquery..)
- - scripts (*.ts & transpiled *.js files - my client scripts)
- - styles (*.css - my client styles)
- Controllers
- - API (Web API Controllers in C# for REST-ful Webservices for AngularJS)
- - Application (ASP.NET MVC Controllers for displaying Views)
- Migrations (EntityFramework, C#)
- Models (Domain-Models, C#)
- Repository (DB-Stuff, C#)
- Services (DB- & other Stuff, C#)
- Typings (library.d.ts - files)
- ViewModels (VM for displaying Views, C#)
- Views (Razor)

My **Project-File (.xproj)** has the following properties set:

```
<TypeScriptModuleKind>CommonJS</TypeScriptModuleKind>
  <TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>True</TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>
  <TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
  <TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>False</TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>
  <TypeScriptRemoveComments>False</TypeScriptRemoveComments>
  <TypeScriptOutFile />
  <TypeScriptOutDir />
  <TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>False</TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>
  <TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>True</TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>
  <TypeScriptSourceMap>True</TypeScriptSourceMap>
  <TypeScriptMapRoot />
  <TypeScriptSourceRoot />
  <TypeScriptEmitDecoratorMetadata>True</TypeScriptEmitDecoratorMetadata>
  <TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>True</TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>
```

The ASP.NET MVC Application is running and I don't have issues with that.
Now, I want to bootstrap the AngularJS-Application.
Herefor I have the following (codesnippet):

**_Layout.cshtml.**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <environment names="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/styles/site.css" />
    </environment>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div id="sidebar">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a asp-controller="App" asp-action="Index">Home</a></li>
            <li><a asp-controller="App" asp-action="About">About</a></li>
            <li><a asp-controller="App" asp-action="Contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="main" class="container-fluid">
        {{ 1+1 }}
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
    </div>

    <environment names="Development">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/underscore/underscore.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

        @RenderSection("scripts", false)

        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/scripts/app.js"></script>
    </environment>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.ts**

```
import * as angular from 'angular'
import 'angular-route'


angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngRoute'
]);
```

So now the app.ts transpiles to the **app.js** the following:

```
define(["require", "exports", 'angular', 'angular-route'], function (require, exports, angular) {
    "use strict";
    angular.module('myApp', [
        'ngRoute'
    ]);
});
//# sourceMappingURL=app.js.map
```

I got the following error (in the browser console) when launching the application:
*ReferenceError: define is not defined*

Now I added **requireJS** to the **_Layout.cshtml** and got the following error:

> Failed to instantiate module myApp due to: [$injector:nomod] Module
>   'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or
>   forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the
>   dependencies as the second argument.

So my question is: How to set up the app.ts 'properly', so I can use it as entry-point for my application?